# Monitoring TeamCity build process

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to see exactly the output of the TeamCity build agent? I suspect that one of the build steps shows a dialog which causes the build process to stop. But logging in to the build agent computer remotely does not give any hints as to what is currently happening.

The build log shows the command that executes before the process stops, but it doesn't show any error message. The actual command is an invocation of sigcheck.exe (from SysInternals). (I tried running this command locally, and it caused a Windows dialog to be shown. I think it contained some license information.)

Answer (score 3):

Because the agent typically runs as a service dialogs will not be displayed.

I'd expect there to be a command line option for sigcheck.exe which turns off ui interaction.

Comment: Just found that there's a relatively undocumented command line switch /accepteula, that does the trick.

Comment: Yep that would do it! It's quite common for command line tools to provide such a switch for situations like this.